# how to validate if lambda query returns null

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I retrieve data from database with lambda like

```
 var obj = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 2).SingleOrDefault().MyColumn;
```

Actually , in `MyTable` , there is no ID with 2 .
So I got this message .

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I validate it properly ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just capture result of query into separate variable and check if any item found before accessing its properties:

```
var yourItem = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 2).SingleOrDefault();
if (yourItem != null)
    obj = yourItem.MyColumn;
```

BTW you can pass predicate into `SingleOrDefault` method:

```
var yourItem = DBContext.MyTable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == 2);
```

Also you can select your property before applying `SingleOrDefault`

```
var obj = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 2)
                           .Select(x => x.MyColumn)
                           .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: @zey I've added one more option - if you need only one property from your object, then you can project results on server side

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is using the ["null-coalescing" `??` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), which will use the second argument if the first argument is null.

`var obj = (DBContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 2) ?? new MyTable()).MyColumn;`

Comment: Using `DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue)` (as @Microtechie suggested) is a far more elegant (and easy to read) way of doing the same thing.  There are places where `??` is very useful, but this isn't really one of them.

Comment: Hi @MosheKatz I tried `DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue)` before trying my answer and it did not work?

Comment: @user2893091 What did you put in as the `defaultValue`?  In your example, it should be `DefaultIfEmpty(new MyTable())`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check first if returned value is null and then access it:

```
var temp = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 2).SingleOrDefault();

if (temp != null)
{
    var obj = temp.MyColumn;
}
```

Not the most elegant way but I do not know any other.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer DefaultIfEmpty() instead of .FirstOrDefault()

and by doing so we can avoid if check

for example

```
var obj = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 2).DefaultIfEmpty().MyColumn;
```

or

```
var obj = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 2).DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty).MyColumn;
```

The  concept of DefaultIfEmpty is simple: it replaces an empty collection with a collection of one default value.

Default value of int is 0. Thus, DefaultIfEmpty on a List yields a List with one zero element.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that `string.Empty` as the "default value" object isn't going to have a `MyColumn` attribute.  The default value in this case needs to be an object of the type represented in the `MyTable` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourItem = DBContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.ID == 2).ToArray()
if(    yourItem.Length > 0)
   //do stuff
```